# How can I shorten my prompt?

Tags: command-line

when i open the terminal, it looks like this (without the *'s)

```
montenrgro@montenrgro-GE620-*******-*******-*****:~/Desktop$
```

the code thing and montenrgro@montenrgro takes up a lot of space, on my laptop. Any way I can decrease it to just: `/home/Desktop`.
I'm sure there is some kinda of specialization to the terminal, but i can't find it. I've tried changing profile but that doesn't seems to work either

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/816068/how-to-shorten-your-command-line-promptbash-like-spatry-does-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to put the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file, if you want the `PS1` (stands for `First Prompt String`) to be permanent:

```
export PS1="\\w$ "
```

Similarly you can also change PS2 or PS3.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the variable `PS1`. So you would do:

```
$ PS1=\\w$
```

to get what you want. You can read the manual page

```
$ man bash
```

and see under "PROMPTING" to read about the different options. Remember that you need to escape a backslash into a double backslash for the codes like `\w`.

Comment: when i write PS1 in the terminal, it gives me command not found

Comment: The command is sensitive to spaces - `PS1=\\w$` should work. (In the shell `foo=bar` sets variable `foo` to `bar`, `foo = bar` calls the program `foo` (if it exists) with arguments ` = bar`).

Comment: edited the answer per chronitis' correction

Answer (score 4):

You should write:

```
export PS1=\\w$
```

in the end of the file ".bashrc" in your home directory.

Or use the command `echo 'export PS1=\\w$' >> ~/.bashrc`, that will do it without needing to open the file with a text editor.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to export this to the environment, just setting the PS1 variable seems to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Using parse_git_branch, the following works as well.

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='NAME\w$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='NAME\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
```

where you replace `NAME` with whatever you want displayed.