# How to shorten your command line prompt (bash) like Spatry does it?

Tags: command-line

I got the following screenshot from a Spatry linux video from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROyqnJg1Ipo

[image: my command line is usually long. so i prefer whole of current path in 1st line and command prompt in next]

I want something like this on every prompt

```
----[myusername@laptop]------[14:30:44]----/mnt/1CFED66BFED63CA8/router/Documents/hacking/1 set up tools/wifiphisher
==>
```

Comment: i want whole of my current pwd to be displayed in 1st line and prompt me in 2nd line

Comment: _shorten_? That prompt is shorter?

Comment: @Jason Day : although 1st line is longer [and will show you long PWD neatly]... the next line prompt gives you plenty of space ... that is the whole idea

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, place a line like:

```
PS1="----[\u@\H]------[\t]----\w\n==> "
```

into your `~/.bashrc` file, which will set your bash prompt to what you want. If you want to change it further, just consult the page http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: okay, i'll change what's in my answer to reflect the prompt you want

Comment: okay got it :-P

Comment: user@machine and time is shown but PWD is not displayed

Comment: sigh, changed it one more time

Comment: @nazar2sfive Yes, next time try to search for yourself instead of repeatedly asking changes to somebody else. There's plenty of documentation about bash prompts, how to insert various information in various formats, with colors, bold, italics etc. Googleing "Bash prompt generator" yields results like [this websites](http://bashrcgenerator.com/) where you can drag&drop the information you want to display with styles etc. It includes a "new line" drag and drop.... in summary: you could just search "bash prompt generator" and obain this answer without having to annoy other people multiple times

Comment: @ Bakuriu ... that's my addiction of copy-paste in linux

Answer (score 8):

Though The question is already answered and accepted, but I still want to suggest  trying using [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it).

It has numerous themes, aliases and completion support for several languages and frameworks, including `git`, `rails`, `svn` and many others.

#### Installation

1. Download the zip archive from here https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/archive/master.zip and extract it in a folder `.bash_it`. This folder would be a hidden folder for starting with a dot(.).
2. Run `~/.bash_it/install.sh` (it automatically backs up your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, depending on your OS)
3. Edit your modified config `~/.bashrc` file in order to customize Bash-it.

   For example if you want to use the `Slick` theme you'd change the line `8` of `~/.bashrc` file to

   ```
    export BASH_IT_THEME='slick'
   ```

The Themes are in `~/.bash_it/themes/` directory.

The available themes screenshot can be viewed here. https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes

Alternatively, you can preview all of them in your shell using the command

```
 BASH_PREVIEW=true reload
```

You can start using them by doing command

```
source ~/.bash_it/themes/<theme-name>/<theme-name>.theme.bash
```

'bobby' theme has a prompt with time included, try using it. You can also customize them.

Comment: i think this is the accurate sparty way

Comment: Since singerng has given the answer according to your need first, I recommend accepting his answer instead. Also It's kinda hurting changing accept :) An upvote is sufficient for an answer to mark it helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Another package which can provide complex shell prompts (originally conceived for prompts in vim but extended to other applications) is powerline.  <https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/shell-prompts.html>

Comment: @JGMiller Thanks for this incredible suggestion! is it available as deb package or in github only?

Comment: @JGMiller Page Not found

Comment: his URL includes a '>' just get rid of that and the page loads

Comment: oh! should have noticed this

Comment: Sorry for late response --  powerline is available as an Ubuntu deb package     https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/powerline   and has its source code on Github at    https://github.com/powerline/powerline

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). You can customize everything.

[image]

Check out more screen shots: [Wiki page (screen shots).](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)