# Which theme is this and how to get it on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, icons, themes

Does anyone recognise this theme and icons? It says Ubuntu 17.04. Is the same theme available for 16.04? Here is [image: the image]

Comment: Where did you get this screenshot from?

Comment: I got when I googled Ubuntu 17.04. Now I saw it actually was a tweet from Ubuntu Budgie (@UbuntuBudgie). Had no idea of it. My bad. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, okay. I actually found that that tweet, which led me to find out what the icon theme is. I will update my answer.

Comment: That is obviously the [Israeli currency symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shekel_sign) reversed: ₪

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like the screenshot is taken from https://twitter.com/UdaraU3/status/792798140403507200, and a followup tweet at https://twitter.com/UdaraU3/status/796319204513370112 states that it is the Budgie Desktop with the Adapta theme and Paper icons.

From http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/install-budgie-desktop-on-ubuntu, to install the Budgie Desktop, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install budgie-desktop budgie-welcome
```

The Adapta theme is developed at https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme. To install the theme, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

From https://snwh.org/paper/download, to install the Paper icons, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snwh/pulp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install paper-icon-theme
```

It looks like the `PS1` in the terminal is also heavily customized. See @Anwar's answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/816091/15003 for ideas on how to customize the `PS1` to fit what is shown in the screenshot.

Comment: That seems to be it. But the minimise, maximise buttons are on the right. Terminal seems different and somehow there are icons on the up-left corner. Is it something which comes in Adapta? Thanks!

Comment: @AlekhKarkadaAshok That looks like the adapta theme applied to the new Budgie Desktop.

Comment: Yes it is. That pic was actually a tweet from Ubuntu Budgie (@UbuntuBudgie). I had no idea it was a new desktop environment. Thanks to you both!

Comment: To complete the answer, you may also want to refer to the `.bash_it` bash customization scripts. Here is the github repo. I wrote an answer before about this too [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/816091/61218)

Comment: @Anwar Wow, nice. I will add a link to your answer.

Comment: @edwinksl Whatever you wish! It seems I missed the github repo link. Here it is https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/

Answer (score 3):

To set the icons you can use dconf-editor or:

```
gsettings set com.solus-project.budgie-wm button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:appmenu'
```

For the gnome windows (like settings) it's:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': ,'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close,maximize,minimize:menu'>}"
```

`close,maximize,minimize:menu` 
would be

```
menu:minimize,maximize,close
```

if you want it the other way around.
Then, if you did not have it:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Start it, set the themes under appearance and enjoy the eye candy :).
Thanks for sharing the PPA's!

[edit]
I noticed that you can start Budgie Welcome from the start menu.
Start it and click default settings.
Then you have the option to install the Arc and Material Design themes.
It seems the Material Design is the one with the transparency.
Click install and then Apply.
[/edit]